# MS Access: Set value as the date of 14th week's Sunday

Tags: database, ms-access

Neither math nor coding are my thing at all, so I'm really hoping someone can help me out with this. I'm thoroughly stumped on this issue...

Scenario: After a client reaches 13 weeks of employment, we begin counting months of retention. So after WeeksTotal reaches 13, the following Sunday marks the beginning of the first month of retention.

So in a nutshell...

When WeeksTotal is <13:
MonthsCurrentJob should equal 0

When WeeksTotal >=13:

1. RetentionStartdate value should be set as the date of the 14th week's Sunday
2. MonthsCurrentJob should then use the RetentionStartdate to calculate months to date
3. 1 should be added to the value of MonthsCurrentJob

This quite possibly (and probably) is the completely wrong way of going about doing this. But I hope this explains what I'm trying to accomplish. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'll sacrifice a goat in your honour. Okay, maybe not... but you'll have my eternal appreciation and admiration!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could calculate like this:

```
RetentionStartdate = DateAdd("ww", 14, DateAdd("d", vbSaturday - Weekday(HireDate), HireDate))
```

From then on, you can count full months:

```
RetentionMonths = Months(RetentionStartDate, Date)
```

using a function like this:

```
Public Function Months( _
  ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
  ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
  Optional ByVal booLinear As Boolean) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full months between datDate1 and datDate2.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   negative differences
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'   negative date/time values (prior to 1899-12-29)
'
' Optionally returns negative counts rounded down to provide a
' linear sequence of month counts.
' For a given datDate1, if datDate2 is decreased stepwise one month from
' returning a positive count to returning a negative count, one or two
' occurrences of count zero will be returned.
' If booLinear is False, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0,  0, -1, -2
' If booLinear is True, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3
'
' If booLinear is False, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results of same absolute Value, only the sign will change.
' This behaviour mimics that of Fix().
' If booLinear is True, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results where the negative count is offset by -1.
' This behaviour mimics that of Int().

' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of months to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
'
' 2010-03-30. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim intDiff   As Integer
  Dim intSign   As Integer
  Dim intMonths As Integer

  ' Find difference in calendar months.
  intMonths = DateDiff("m", datDate1, datDate2)
  ' For positive resp. negative intervals, check if the second date
  ' falls before, on, or after the crossing date for a 1 month period
  ' while at the same time correcting for February 29. of leap years.
  If DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2) > 0 Then
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", intMonths, datDate1), datDate2))
    intDiff = Abs(intSign < 0)
  Else
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", -intMonths, datDate2), datDate1))
    If intSign <> 0 Then
      ' Offset negative count of months to continuous sequence if requested.
      intDiff = Abs(booLinear)
    End If
    intDiff = intDiff - Abs(intSign < 0)
  End If

  ' Return count of months as count of full 1 month periods.
  Months = intMonths - intDiff

End Function
```

Now, for use in a query, create a helper function:

```
Public Function RetentionMonths(ByVal HireDate As Date) As Integer

    Dim RetentionStartdate As Date

    RetentionStartdate = DateAdd("ww", 14, DateAdd("d", vbSaturday - Weekday(HireDate), HireDate))

    RetentionMonths = Months(RetentionStartDate, Date)

End Function
```

Save this function in your code module, and your query could look like:

```
Select *, RetentionMonths([HireDate]) As RetentionMonths
From YourTable
```

Comment: Gustav, thank you so much for your response! Unfortunately there's something I'm obviously not getting right. I'm trying to run the function in VBA using ?Months(date1,date2), but no matter what dates I input, I always get 0. I am continuing to mess with it though -- I'm sure it's probably a really silly error I'm making. :)

Comment: Make sure your date1 and date2 are true date values.

Comment: Thank you sir, that was definitely the issue :) I hate to ask anything else of you -- but could you possibly just clarify where I am to place the first two lines of code? It seems everywhere I try to put them, it has some issue with it... VBA code doesn't like the "ww", putting it on a form just gives me "#Name?" and as an expression, it's saying it contains a syntax error... I'm so sorry to bother you, I'm clearly still learning the basics. I really deeply appreciate your time helping my hopeless newbie self!

Comment: Not a problem, Gustav! I greatly appreciate your help, and I'm learning a lot. (Mostly that I should've told the boss to stop being cheap and hire an actual professional to do this!!) Alright, so I'm getting somewhere!! Haha. Only issue now -- my result is incorrect, and I'm not sure why. Seems to consistently be 3 less than it should be. For example, with a startdate of 2017-03-01, the result ought to be 4, but I'm getting 1. 2017-01-01 gives 3, but should be 6. But, definitely getting somewhere!

Comment: You could post a list of values and the expected results (and why). That might show something.

Comment: It works now! It's a miracle! Just had to go through the code again to understand how it was working, and I found my error. :) Gustav, I can't thank you enough. If you're ever in need of a kidney, hit me up. ;)